# innerHTML to DOM elements with Mootools 1.3

Tags: javascript, mootools, innerhtml

Well, is it possible? thank you for your help

**EDIT**

I mean, if I have an HTML string, say 
`"<div id="something"><input /><div>something else<span>yet something else</span></div></div>"` can I do something like `var elements = that_string.to_element` ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Can you show us your code and explain? In short, Mootools (and Prototype.js, and jQuery, …) is merely a framework *on top of* JavaScript, anything you can do in JavaScript you can do using Mootools et al.

Comment: you can use `element.set("html", "blah <img src='foo.jpg' />");` to set it and `element.get("html")` to read it. other than that, not sure what you mean. voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I agree with last sentence of Dimitar :D
..indeed innerHTML is possible with Mootools 1.3!

demo => http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/Ae4Wz/

Markup:

```
<div id="duck"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
//Mootools 
$('duck').set('html','booooo'); //to retrieve html $('duck').get('html')

//or 
$('duck').innerHTML += '<br />boooooooooommm';

//Std javascript
var duck = document.getElementById('duck');

duck.innerHTML += '<br />ahah';
```